# Sub model change event does not propagate to parent model in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So i got this sub model associate to 1 list item of my view, when I edit this model, the view is re rendered correctly.

But I also got other things parent do when the complete list model change, and the change event is not firing at the aprent level which is weird,

if I manually fire model.change() I see the content updated from the submodel (meaning the parent model as effectively changed).

Is there an automatic way to propagate the change event to the parent model?

Comment: can you provide some code examples of how you have it set up now, and how you want it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your "parent" the collection in which the sub-model belongs?  If so, the collection will receive a change notification whenever an attributes of the sub-model changes.  Here's an example that demonstrates the model / collection change event:

```
var Product = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Products = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Product
});

var ProductsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.bind('change', this.onProductChange, this);
    },
    onProductChange: function (product) {
        console.log('product with ID ' + product.get('id') + ' changed to ' + product.get('name'));
    }
});

var products = new Products([{ id: 1, name: 'Book' }, { id: 2, name: 'Toy' }, { id: 3, name: 'Shirt'}]);
new ProductsView({collection:products});

products.get(1).set({ name: 'TV' }); // console: product with ID 1 changed to TV
```

On the other hand, if your "parent" is not a collection of your sub-model and there's simply a parent/child relationship, then Backbone has no way to know about the relationship, so you will need to trigger the change event on the parent whenever a child changes. For example:

```
    var Parent = Backbone.Model.extend({
        includeChild: function (child) {
            child.bind('change', this.onChildChange, this);
        },
        onChildChange: function (child) {
            console.log('Child with name ' + child.get('name') + ' changed.');
        }
    });
    var Child = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    var parent = new Parent();
    var child = new Child({ name: 'Bob', parent: parent });
    parent.includeChild(child);

    child.set({name: 'Joe'}); // console: Child with name Joe changed.
```

Here's a complete list of Backbone events: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-events

Answer (score 1):

I like JohnnyO's solution, and I've used his solution to make a generic "SuperModel" class in my application. Here is the Coffeescript version of this class, which allows the registration of child models with a parent and automatically propagates all events:

```
class Model.SuperModel extends Backbone.Model

  includeChild: (id, model) ->
    @set id, model
    @listenTo model, 'all', @trigger
```

And that's it. Using it is easy:

```
parent = new Model.SuperModel()
parent.includeChild('child', new Backbone.Model())

view = new Backbone.View()
view.listenTo(parent, 'change', -> console.log "parent changed!")

parent.get('child').set('foo', 'bar')
```

This will print out "parent changed", as you would expect.